# Combine array elements to 2 dim array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an data array(All value of Array A are `string`) :
Here is the data input( http://pastebin.com/H8wv9aJU )

```
 $A = Array
  0=>(
      [0] => "03"//main
      [1] => "04"//sub
      [2] => "05"
      [3] => "07"

  [4] => "03" //main
    [5] => "04"//sub
      [6] => "05"
      [7] => "06"
      [8] => "07"
    [9] => "04"//sub
      [10] => "05"
      [11] => "06"
      [12] => "07"
    [13] => "04"//sub
      [14] => "05"
      [15] => "07"

  [16] => "03" //main 
    [17] => "04"//sub
      [18] => "05"
      [19] => "06"
      [20] => "07"
    [21] => "04"//sub
      [22] => "05"
      [23] => "06"
      [24] => "07"
    [25] => "04"//sub
      [26] => "05"
      [27] => "07"
  );
```

The expected result(some elements between 04 and 07 can be missing):

```
Array
(
[0] => Array // "03"
    (
    [0] => "030405  07" //because missing 06 see here 2 space
    )

[1] => Array // "03"
    (
    [0] => "0304050607" //concatenate it all together
    [1] => "0304050607"//concatenate it all together
    [2] => "030405  07"//because missing 06see here 2 space
    )

[2] => Array // "03"
    (
    [0] => "0304050607" //concatenate it all together
    [1] => "0304050607" //concatenate it all together
    [2] => "030405  07"//because missing 06, see here 2 space
    )

)
```

I am tried:

```
$r = -1;
$organized_array = array();//array expected result. 
foreach($A as $key=>$rec) {
    if(substr($rec,0,2) == "03") {
        // CHANGE 1
      $save = $rec;// saved "03" yo put in child too.
      ++$r;//inc parent => $r became 0
        $j = 0; // child 
        $organized_array[$r][$j] = str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), "",$rec);
      }
         else {
          //I STUCKED HERE FOR GETTING THE EXPECTED RESULT
        if (($j % 3) > 0) $rec =  str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), "",$rec);
        // CHANGE 2
        else if ($j && $j % 3 == 0) $rec = str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), "",$save.$rec);
        $organized_array[$r][floor($j / 3)] .= str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), "", $rec);
        ++$j;//increment child
    }
}
```

Could anybody What Did I wrong ?

Comment: Sorry, the two datasets you gave aren't very helpful (they have a lot of the same numbers, hard to tell what is going where), could you give another example?  And don't the plus signs go on the other side of the number? $k++ not ++$k.

Comment: edited maybe more clear now,thanks

Comment: and the values can only be 03,04,05,06, and 07?

Comment: @mazzzzz you can increment on either post or pre var. The increment works differently though see http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php

Comment: yes you are right i missing "" all value as String,.thanks

Comment: @lEnAk: Please provide the arrays outputted with `var_export` so that we can just copy and paste them.

Comment: @Treffynnon I never knew that, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: And is this how the array should be formatted? http://pastebin.com/PrueYRc9

Comment: I still can't figure out pattern between data array and expected result, maybe that's just me!

Comment: value start "03" became main otherwise value became sub of multi-array.and sub-elements concatenate it value together plus its main value. thanks for questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is solution for your problem...

If you have array like this

```
$A = array("03", "04", "05", "07", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "04", "05",
"06", "07", "04", "05", "07", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "04", "05", "06",
"07", "04", "05", "07");
```

...and expected output like this:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "030405  07"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "0304050607"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "0304050607"
    [2]=>
    string(10) "030405  07"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "0304050607"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "0304050607"
    [2]=>
    string(10) "030405  07"
  }
}
```

**try THIS CODE!**

```
$r = -1; $r2 = 0; $last_rec = 2;
$organized_array = array();
foreach ($A as $key => $rec) {
  if ($rec == "03") {
    // parent
    if ($r >= 0) $organized_array[$r][$r2] = str_pad($organized_array[$r][$r2], 10, '  ');
    $r++;
    $r2 = 0;
    $organized_array[$r][$r2] = "03";
    }
  else {
    // children
    $this_rec = $rec * 1;
    if ($this_rec < $last_rec) {
      $organized_array[$r][$r2] = str_pad($organized_array[$r][$r2], 10, '  ');
      $r2++;
      $organized_array[$r][$r2] = "03";
      }
    if ($this_rec > ($last_rec + 1)) {
      $ec = $this_rec - $last_rec - 1;
      $organized_array[$r][$r2] .= str_repeat("  ", $ec);
      }
    $organized_array[$r][$r2] .= $rec;
    }
  $last_rec = $rec * 1;
  }

var_dump($organized_array);
```

Hope that helps!